# Filtering out NULLs in a query

Tags: sql, null, filtering

The following subquery is returning some nulls and some values. i want to select the rows that are not null, how would i do this?

```
        ,(select distinct LEDGERTABLE.ACCOUNTNAME
    FROM ledgertrans 
    Where Salesline.SalesID = #tempCMs.SALESID and salesline.DIMENSION = 
        (Select top 1 Ledgertrans.Dimension
        From LedgerTrans
            Where Ledgertrans.Voucher = #tempCms.InvoiceID and LedgerTrans.AccountNum = Ledgertable.Accountnum)
 ) As 'Account'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Filter `NULL`s with  `IS NOT NULL`

Try this:

```
(select distinct LEDGERTABLE.ACCOUNTNAME
    FROM ledgertrans 
    Where Salesline.SalesID = #tempCMs.SALESID and salesline.DIMENSION = 
        (Select top 1 Ledgertrans.Dimension
        From LedgerTrans
            Where Ledgertrans.Voucher = #tempCms.InvoiceID 
            and LedgerTrans.AccountNum = Ledgertable.Accountnum
            AND LEDGERTABLE.ACCOUNTNAME IS NOT NULL)
 ) As 'Account'
```

`NULL` values **are not** filtered with an equality test ( `!= NULL` ) because a `NULL` value is unknown, and therefore equality cannot be determined.

Answer (score 2):

Add `AND LEDGERTABLE.ACCOUNTNAME IS NOT NULL` to your `WHERE` clause.